# How to decode Google's proprietary latLon format for China?

Tags: google-maps, json

This Google Maps [link](http://ditu.google.cn/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=zh-CN&geocode=&q=train+station&sll=31.21515,121.473083&sspn=1.283677,1.424103&brcurrent=3,0x35b27040b1f53c33:0x295129423c364a1,0%3B5,0,0&ie=UTF8&hq=train+station&hnear=&z=10) returns train stations in Shanghai, China. By appending '&output=js' it [returns it in JSON](http://ditu.google.cn/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=zh-CN&geocode=&q=train+station&sll=31.21515,121.473083&sspn=1.283677,1.424103&brcurrent=3,0x35b27040b1f53c33:0x295129423c364a1,0%3B5,0,0&ie=UTF8&hq=train+station&hnear=&z=10&output=js) format. I'm trying to decode the format Google uses for lat/lon:

```
latlng:{
    lat:0,
    lng:0,
    alt:{
        ll:"35122131713574191160",
        mode:2
    }
}
```

For all other countries, Google returns the lat lon values separated in the `lat` and `lon` . Only for China they return this strange `ll` value. Does anybody know how to decode it?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like a lat, lng in decimal degrees (35.1221317, 135.74191160)...not sure if it's actually that simple. A brief search didn't turn up any documentation on this so I'm just posting a comment...maybe someone else with have more concrete insight.

Comment: @Swingley: Unfortunately, that's not true. Shanghai is at 31.2,121.5.

Comment: Alt= height above sea level - so it's 11m

Comment: @Mapperz: 11m? How do you come to that value? And what does that long `35122131713574191160` number mean, then?

Comment: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html works in English.

Comment: For Train Stations - 陆家嘴站 Shanghai, China (etc) works

Comment: @Mapperz: My question is not how to search but how to interpret the returned latlng structure. I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the returned results.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear that the returned `ll` value encodes the latitude and longitude, it may just be some other piece of information they embed with the results.  If it does encode the latitude and longitude, I'd go looking the way of [geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and coordinate interleaving, both of which provide a conversion mechanism between single strings and a coordinate pair. If you're convinced that they are related, try gathering up a collection of values and try your hand at a linear solver or the like to deduce their relationship.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. Not sure though, I'm able to do the math to solve it. I'll extract some values and see if a relationship seems obvious.